# Sublime Text: how to show only filenames in text search, or to "collapse all" results?

Tags: sublimetext2

When doing a text search in Sublime Text, is there a way to only show the filenames that matched, and **not** show the actual lines that matched and the context around those lines?

I can go through each file and collapse those lines (mouseover the column between the line number in the first column and filename in the third column, reveal an arrow icon, click that arrow icon) -- is there a way to easily collapse all of them?

Sublime Text 2, v2.0.1, build 2217

Comment: The default Find does not provide such formatting options and I quickly checked such plug-in does not seem to exist.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had been wondering about this myself, but apparently the answer was simple. Use **code folding.**

Go to the menu **Edit** > **Code Folding** > **Fold All**. The keyboard shortcut on Mac is <kbd>⌘K</kbd>, then <kbd>⌘1</kbd>

### Normal results:

[image: Unfolded code]

### (Partially) folded results:

[image: Partially folded/collapsed code]

Apparently it doesn't work too well—some results stay unfolded, both in ST2 and ST3—but it's something.

Comment: Thanks it worked like a magic.  What is the shortcut for the opposite of this? to expand all?

Comment: It looks like it's `⌘K`, then `⌘J`. You can see it in the command palette (`⇧⌘P`)

Comment: I like this answer better because it uses an already useful feature and does not require installation.

Comment: Works perfectly using sublime text 3065

Comment: In ST3, there is this nice keyboard shortcut  `Ctrl + Shift + [` for Fold (and with `]` to Unfold), that will fold/unfold the one file result under cursor. This is usefull if you are walking through the results and want to hide the irrelevant/reviewed parts.

Answer (score 4):

The way I deal with this is to perform the search, copy the entire result output and paste it into a new document.  Then use 'Search Files' (ctrl-shift-F) and search that result file for "C:\Users\" with 'Show Context' deselected.  That gives me a list of just the files and paths.

[image]

Comment: Where do you deselect "Show Context"?

Comment: Sorry @pixelwiz, I missed that comment, see updated answer.

Comment: The accepted answer is probably better for the question, but I like this one better.  Never noticed that little button in 5+ years of using ST3